# Backload -Errorcode-12 : Exception occured while storing the file

Tags: file-upload, upload, backload

I have some issue in uploading file using JQueryFileUpload with Backload.

I have added settings in web.config to upload large file like 1 GB file allow.

When i try to upload zip file around 150MB it upload successfully but when i try to upload file around 200 MB it showing following exception.

errorcode:12
error: Exception occured while storing the file

Can you please help me to get the solution? Why i am getting above error?

I have one other question : can we use UNC path to save image outside of website folder? If yes then how we can use?

Thanks in advance.